# Run minutely cronjobs in parallel

Tags: cron

I have a minutely cronjob running on Openshift. This cronjob executes an URL that usually takes 5 minutes to run (it's used to generate reports).

I was expecting multiple instances of the cronjob to execute my URL at the same time (in parallel), but at the moment it's only running one each time.

My question is: does the next minutely task only get triggered when the previous one finishes? Or it is being triggered but my ASP.NET application is refusing it to run due to the same session ID (I'm guessing)?

If I try to access the same URL on my browser using different tabs only the first one will run while the second one will be hanging waiting for the first one to finish (this is due to the same session ID so the server knows it's the "same person"). Not sure if crons are affected by sessions as well?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably the second case, an error, as `crond` will usually blindly launch a new instance each minute and if those jobs take longer than a minute to run... well let's say the system can get very very slow as the system thrashes itself to a yeah let's reboot that box.